# iOS7 style mapview callout segue in the callout (calloutAccessoryControlTapped, UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure)

Tags: ios, mkmapview, segue, mkannotationview, callouts

I have mapview on iPad with annotations and callouts, each callout also has rightCalloutAccessoryView with detail disclosure button. I see the stock Maps app performs segue for callout details within the callout's object. It first performs a transition of the view from right to left like a push segue, then resizes the callout frame based on the detail's content.

How should I configure the segue in storyboard to be performed within the original callout and not replace the entire screen? Is it a push segue or popover? If it's popover, how should I configure anchor and passthrough?

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"contactDetail" sender:self];
}
```

[image]